# Lendo valores de um arquivo em C

Tags: c, arquivo

Eu tenho um arquivo contendo os seguintes valores:

```
10 20 30
40 50 60
```

Para cada linha, os valores devem estar armazenados em um vetor.

Como faço para obter tais valores do arquivo, sabendo que não existe uma quantidade exata para cada linha ?

Comment: Já tentas te fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: @CesarMiguel , já tentei de tudo: fgets, fgetc, fscanf...

Comment: Considerando que há pelo menos um inteiro em cada linha, leia um int e um char. Se o char for \n ou EOF, acabou a linha/arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Vou assumir que voce sabe ler cada uma das linhas do seu arquivo, ok?

Esse codigo aqui pega cada numero de uma linha:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char linha[] = "10 100 1000";
    char *num;
    int x;
    num = strtok(linha, " \n\r");
    while (num != NULL) {
        sscanf(num, "%d", &x);
        printf("%d\n", x);
        num = strtok(NULL, " \n\r");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O que ele faz e `tokenizar` a linha, isto e, ele extrai os elementos da string `linha`. Esses elementos sao as 'coisas' entre espacos ou o fim da linha, logo, os numeros.